# how to clone Ubuntu with multiple disk with RAID 1 configuration to a new system with almost same hardware

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, raid, clone

I'm wondering if it's possible to clone a pre-configured Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system to a new system with almost the same hardware.  I had some experience cloning a single drive setup but not multiple drives with RAID configuration.

The original system had the following hard disk configuration:

1)  256GB SSD  -  partitioned as ext4 "/" and boot loader location.

2)  1TB RAID 1 md0  -  partitioned as ext4 "/home"

What is the best way to clone above drives to new system (with same drives setup)?  And what is the proper process?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a fork of old program "remastersys", called "linux respin", it has available a gui for using desktop environment , and either a script for command line.. 
essentially it does put all (not the folders explicitly excluded into the configuration file file)  into an iso that you can write into a cd or pen drive usb or virtual environment..
And most important it doesn't matter the new hardware characteristics, it will run as live or if you want you can install using the icon into the desktop on all machine you want.and in either cases you will have already  the old configuration files and folders (data included)!
Beware only to 32/64bit because you cannot install 64bit into 32bit hardware..

Cheers

Comment: You can improve your answer with screen shots and step by step instructions.